# Need example for data binding to Winform control BackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I've been using databinding extensively for my C# Winforms application GUI field settings.  Now I would like to control a button color using the same mechanism.  But I'm encountering an exception: "Cannot format the value to the desired type."
The relevant code sections are:

```
public static UserInputs userInputs = new UserInputs();

public class UserInputs : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e){};

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {   
            try { PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) ); }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e) { }
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnore] private System.Drawing.Color _applyGmmColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
    [XmlIgnore] public System.Drawing.Color ApplyGmmColor {
        get { return _applyGmmColor; }
        set {
            _applyGmmColor = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
buttonApplyGmm.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", userInputs, "ApplyGmmColor", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

when I attempt to change the button background color by changing the value of userInputs.ApplyGmmColor, I get this exception:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Cannot format the value to the desired type.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.FormatObject(Object value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.PushData(Boolean force)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.UpdateIsBinding()
       at System.Windows.Forms.PropertyManager.UpdateIsBinding()
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingManagerBase.PushData(Boolean& success)
       at System.Windows.Forms.PropertyManager.OnCurrentChanged(EventArgs ea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.PropValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor.OnValueChanged(Object component, EventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.OnValueChanged(Object component, EventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.OnINotifyPropertyChanged(Object component, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at ADT.UserInputs.NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName) in C:\Users\rmpe01\Documents\GitHub_2017.1\AnomalyDetectionToolbox\ADT\UserInputs.cs:line 38
       at ADT.UserInputs.set_ApplyGmmColor(Color value) in C:\Users\rmpe01\Documents\GitHub_2017.1\AnomalyDetectionToolbox\ADT\UserInputs.cs:line 108
       at ADT.UseModel.setApplyButtonColor(ACTIVE_SENSOR_TYPE st, Color c) in C:\Users\rmpe01\Documents\GitHub_2017.1\AnomalyDetectionToolbox\ADT\UseModel.cs:line 31
       at ADT.UseModel.touch() in C:\Users\rmpe01\Documents\GitHub_2017.1\AnomalyDetectionToolbox\ADT\UseModel.cs:line 47
       at ADT.ADT.comboBoxGmmComputeInterval_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\rmpe01\Documents\GitHub_2017.1\AnomalyDetectionToolbox\ADT\Form1.cs:line 2370
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_Text(String value)
  InnerException:
```

I've found lots of examples of data binding control values, but very little effecting control attributes like background color.

I am looking for a **simple** example that demonstrates how handle BackColor (or similar) control attribute without adding a lot of additional code over the standard approach.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: The code you've posted should and does work.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  I edited the post to include the detailed exception listing.

Comment: You are welcome. But information is not enough (it's unclear which binding is failing). I've created a simple form with single standard button, used your code to bind it and it works. So the problem is not related to the button BackColor binding, in order to get help you need to create [mcve], i.e. some minimal, but full code that we can copy/paste, run and see the issue.